# how to change configurable product SKU programmatically in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, simple-product

Change configurable product SKU programmatically into associated product and custom option are removed using this code.

```
$_product = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $old_sku);
$_product->setSku($new_sku)->save();
```